# Is there a way to transform rails multiparameter datetime to datetime?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Using rails, I've found that datetime attributes are send in parts.

Having the need to converted them into a date time I had to do

```
DateTime.new(params[:event]["date_from(1i)"],params[:event]["date_from(2i)"], params[:event]["date_from(3i)"],params[:event]["date_from(4i)"],params[:event]["date_from(5i)"])
```

I was wondering if I could do this in a more elegant way. Is it possible?

Comment: can you not change the elements on the form so that it returns in the format you want, or are these individual drop-downs?

Answer (score 2):

If you have an ActiveRecord Event model the easiest way is to just use its built in multiparameter assignment:

```
event = Event.new(params.fetch(:event).permit(:date_from))
event.date_from
```

This is handled by [`ActiveRecord::AttributesAssignment`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/f95c0b7e96eb36bc3efc0c5beffbb9e84ea664e4/activerecord/lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb#L40) and unfortunatly it has not been extracted out to ActiveModel (yet).

If you have to do it from scratch you can do it by extracting the multiparams, converting it into a hash, sorting the hash and extracting its values:

```
datetime = begin
  parts = params.fetch(:event).permit(:datefrom).to_h
  if parts.any?
    Hash[parts.sort].values.then do |array|
      DateTime.new(*array)
    end
  else
    nil
  end
rescue TypeError, ActionController::ParameterMissing
  # @todo Handle invalid input
  nil
end
```

Answer (score -1):

```
time_keys = [
 "datefrom(1i)", 
 "datefrom(2i)", 
 "datefrom(3i)", 
 "datefrom(4i)", 
 "datefrom(5i)", 
 "datefrom(6i)"
]
DateTime.new(*(params[:event].slice(*time_keys).values))
```

Comment: You can just use `params.fetch(:event).permit(:datefrom)` instead as strong parameters can deal with multiparameter attributes.

Comment: You should explain why your answer actually answers the original question.